# war project dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

I need to access one bean class from war project into my another war project. The bean class is exists in MyProject. I wrote pom of another project called NewProject as follows.

```
<groupId>MyProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version> 
</parent>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Is it possible to add war dependency in another war project?

Comment: See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1991

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The given issue is not related to the problem here. The issue is about transitive dependencies which here is not the case.

Answer (score 22):

If you configure the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) with the following attribute:

```
<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
```

you would get an supplemental artifact with the following coordinates:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
 <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

which contains all classes within your war project which can be used as dependency which is a jar file which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

In your war project

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<configuration>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
</configuration></plugin>
```

It creates a classes artifact which you can use in the required project

```
<dependency>
<groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
<artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
<version>your-version</version>
<classifier>classes</classifier>
```

refer [maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses)

hope it helps...

Comment: `Now acceptance your project`...? I have no clue what you're trying to say. Could you correct this?

Comment: It creates a classes artifact which you can use in the required project.

Comment: Read the quoted sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies work using jars, and you would normally define a common dependency in a `.jar` file that can be accessed by both `.war`s. That's not Maven-specific, but how dependencies in Java work. The internal structure of a `.war` is different from a .jar in terms of how the classes are laid out.

Consequently in Maven, I would expect to define a `.jar` project, and then two `.war` projects both depending on the initial project.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off IMHO creating a `jar`  with your `war` classes that are needed in your project.

And then just add the dependency to your project configuration (`classifier` classes).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>classes</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your re-usable classes into a separate module. This will help:

- Test things quicker.
- Use the code as a dependency in other projects.

Alternatively, you could produce a classes only jar by using the `maven-jar-plugin` and producing a classifier-based artifact. However, I think my suggestion is better in the fact that it give you a clear separation of the code and forces you to organize your code better.